# How to remove value (not key) from NSmutableDictionary

Tags: ios, uitableview, nsmutabledictionary

I have a NSmutableDictionary which I use it to fill in the tableView. Now I want to make the rows in my tableView editable. Here is my code:

```
- (BOOL)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView canEditRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    return YES;

}
```

And when one select the row

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView commitEditingStyle:(UITableViewCellEditingStyle)editingStyle forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    if (editingStyle == UITableViewCellEditingStyleDelete) {
        // Delete the row from the data source
        //Below four lines to get the name of course to delete

        NSString *key = [[self sectionKeys] objectAtIndex:[indexPath section]];//This is the key
        NSArray *contents = [[self sectionContents] objectForKey:key];
        NSString *contentForThisRow = [contents objectAtIndex:[indexPath row]];//This is the value

        [_sectionContents removeObjectForKey:key];//this can delete the key,not fit here, should delete value
         NSLog(@"Dictionary: %@", [_sectionContents description]);//test dictionary here
        [tableView deleteRowsAtIndexPaths:@[indexPath] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];
    }
}
```

Here, my situation is one key may have *more than one* values, so when user select the row to delete, above code will delete the whole key with other values, which is not what I want, and it also generate error.

So my question is instead of using `removeObjectForKey`, what is the correct way to only remove value but not key from the dictionary please?

Here is the code I populate my dictionary:

```
//New code for populating dictionary
    if ([_sectionContents objectForKey:AddKey] != nil) {
        //Already exist a value for the key
        id object = [_sectionContents objectForKey:AddKey];
        NSMutableArray *objectArray;
        //objectArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
        if ([object isKindOfClass:[NSMutableArray class]]) {//if object is a mutableArray already

            objectArray = (NSMutableArray *)object;
            //NSLog(@"1.The code runs through here!");
        } else {//If object is not array, it means that only one value exists here.

            //The following convert string to correct format
            NSString *oldCourse=nil;

            if ([object isKindOfClass:[NSString class]]) {
                oldCourse = object;
            } else if ([object respondsToSelector:@selector(stringValue)]) {
                oldCourse = [object stringValue];
            } else if ([object respondsToSelector:@selector(description)]) {
                oldCourse = [object description];
            }

           NSString *newString = [[oldCourse componentsSeparatedByCharactersInSet:[NSCharacterSet newlineCharacterSet]] componentsJoinedByString:@" "];//remove newline
            NSString * newString2 = [newString substringWithRange:NSMakeRange(7, [newString length]-7)];//cut the front
            //To erase the symbols
            NSString *newString3 = [newString2 stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@")" withString:@""];
            NSString *newString4 = [newString3 stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"\"" withString:@""];

            //NSLog(@"%@",newString4);
            //if ([oldCourse isKindOfClass:[NSString class]])
            //NSLog(@"Become string here!");

            objectArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
            if(![objectArray containsObject:newString4])
                if(![_msgCourse containsObject:newString4])
             [objectArray insertObject:newString4 atIndex:0];
           // NSLog(@"2.The code runs through here!");
        //NSMutableArray *objectArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
        }
        NSLog(@"%@",objectArray);

        NSString *message;
        if([objectArray containsObject:course])//Giving out warning if course retaken
        {UIAlertView *alert=[[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Error: this course have been selected already." message:message delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:@"Return to course planner" otherButtonTitles:nil, nil];

            [alert show];}

        if(![objectArray containsObject:course] && ![course isEqualToString:[objectArray objectAtIndex:0]] &&
           ![_msgCourse containsObject:course])
                   [objectArray addObject:course];

        if(![_msgCourse containsObject:course])//Use this flag to avoid retake class
            [_msgCourse addObject:course];

        //NSLog(@"3.The code runs through here!");

        [_sectionContents setObject:objectArray forKey:AddKey];
    } else {
        //No value for the key, add new value
        NSString *message;
        if([_msgCourse containsObject:course])//If course existed
        {
            UIAlertView *alert=[[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Error: this course have been selected already." message:message delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:@"Return to course planner" otherButtonTitles:nil, nil];

                [alert show];
        }

       if(![_msgCourse containsObject:course])
       {
           [_sectionContents setObject:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:course,nil] forKey:AddKey];
           [_msgCourse addObject:course];
       }

    }
```

Comment: How can a key have more than one value?

Comment: @trojanfoe, they have implemented buckets: `NSArray *contents = [[self sectionContents] objectForKey:key];`

Comment: @trojanfoe May be value contains array of values.

Comment: Ok, so the question is "how to remove a value from an array".

Comment: It seems it is yeah :) Seems like a case of overthought

Comment: But then the OP doesn't know which value to remove.  The model is broken.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I understood correctly, you trying to remove element from section, but actually deleting the whole section. You should do next:

```
NSString *key = [_sectionKeys objectAtIndex:[indexPath section]];//This is the key
NSMutableArray *contents = _sectionContents[key];
//Delete only selected row
[contents removeObjectAtIndex:indexPath.row]
```

This should work.

Comment: Thank you very much for your reply, but it gives out error like "mutableCopy not found on object of type 'id'", what does it mean please?

Comment: @user4441082 Don't use property syntax to call methods.

Comment: @user4441082 updated my answer, creating NSMutableArray properly.

Comment: Hi, thank you for your update. there seems to be error in last line. Saying "no visible @interface for 'NSMutableArray' declare the selector "setObject:for Key:"

Comment: @user4441082 yes, sorry. Updated sectionContents instead of sectionKeys

Comment: Hi, your update make sense to me. But xcode says the last line "subscripted value is not an array,pointer or vector"...

Comment: @user4441082 Ok, actually the first question that I had ask is what is sectionContext and what is stored inside it? It would be great to see your code, where this collection is creating. Please, add it to your question.

Comment: Thanks for your patience. Please my update, where my dictionary sectionContext is populated.

Comment: @user4441082 The last guess. Please, change NSArray to NSMutableArray here while setting new object               
          if(![_msgCourse containsObject:course])
       {
           [_sectionContents setObject:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:course,nil] forKey:AddKey];
           [_msgCourse addObject:course];
       }
And remove last line from my answer (setObject:forKey)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/77220/discussion-between-4esterua-and-user4441082).

Comment: Thanks, both you and james have given me great help. I will figure it out by myself.

Answer (score 3):

Since the values of your key-value pairs are arrays: `NSArray *contents = [[self sectionContents] objectForKey:key];`, what you actually need to know is how to remove an element from an array.

This is simply:

```
//Need a mutable version. I've assumed it isn't already mutable. If it is, you can 
//adjust accordingly.

NSMutableArray *contents = [[self sectionContents][key] mutableCopy];
id object = /* You need to determine which element to remove */;
[contents removeObject:object];

//Put the modified array back into the dictionary
[self sectionContents][key] = contents;
```

Comment: Ok thanks. I'll keep an eye on it in case it's approved

Comment: Thanks James, your method is easy to understand,but it give out error on "mutableCopy", saying "mutableCopy not found on object of type 'id'", what does it mean please?

Comment: It means I've made a bit of a mistake ;) I didn't use an IDE, and wrote it from memory. Gimme 2 mins to fix it

Comment: I'm not sure what it means... I can call `mutableCopy` on an `id` fine in a little test I just wrote.

Comment: @user4441082, Does your dictionary contain *only* arrays? And is the error at compile time or run time?

Comment: I did this as a test: `NSMutableDictionary *d = @{@"Key" : @[ @"string", [NSObject new], @1 ]}.mutableCopy;
 d[@"Key2"] = @"string";
 d[@"Key3"] = [NSObject new];
 id array = d[@"Key"];
 NSMutableArray *contents = [array mutableCopy];` It compiled fine :S

Comment: Thank you very much, James. I think some structure error exist in my code. I will check it out by myself. Thanks again for your hint.